# Java - Evaluating a condition given in string form

Tags: java, reflection

So I have a string that is made of three parts: `fieldName`, `operator` and `value`

Assuming the parameters have these values:

```
fieldName: firstName
operator: equals
value: Nikola
```

I want to be able to evaluate that, `firstName equals Nikola` as a condition with the help of Java reflections. Is this possible?
`if(obj.getFirstName().equals(value))`

**Edit** (*Xenteros*):
According to the discussion in the comments, I decided to add the explanation to the question as the `MCVE` should be in the question itself:

Problem description:
There is a class which has multiple fields, all of them contain Strings. There is a request for a solution to get the field value by field's name and compare to another `String`.
There are multiple operators available. For example: `<`, `<=`, `>=` etc, but there is also `equals` available which was unfortunately added as an example before. If the user passes `"equals"` to the method, `equals` should be invoked.

Example input:
`User u`, such that `u.firstName.equals("John")`)
`"firstName"`,
`"John"`,
`"<="`.

Expected output:

`true`

Comment: I have already gotten the values of the three parameters, I just need to form them into a condition

Comment: Just post the files you have tried

Comment: what is the purpose you want to try this ?

Comment: Do you know how to call a method through reflection? If not, [look it up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string). Otherwise, what are you stuck on?

Comment: @Kei did my answer help?

Comment: Sorry, I went on a break. Let me try it out.

Comment: And the operator isn't a method

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The `operator` is not a method.

Comment: what is it then? what kind of an operator is "equals"?

Comment: a.equals(b). String comparator. There are others like >= and <= for numbers, and !=

Comment: equals is a method. It's not an operator.

Comment: Its named as 'operator'. Bad naming sense on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking about reflection:

Let's assume that you have an object called obj.

```
Field field = obj.getClass().getField(fieldName);
Method method = field.getType().getMethod(operator, Object.class); //in case you mean method

if (method.invoke(field.get(), value) {}
```

Remember to surround it with `try-catch` as there are many possibilities of Exceptions to be thrown.

According to your update to the question I suggest the following:

```
boolean check(Object obj, String fieldName, String operator, String value) throws IllegalArgumentException, someOtherExceptions {
    Field field = obj.getClass().getField(fieldName);
    if (operator.equals("equals") {
        return field.get().equals(value);
    }
    if (operator.equals("<=")) {
        return field.get().compareTo(value) <=0;
    }
    if (operator.equals("<")) {
        return field.get().compareTo(value) < 0;
    //other operators impl.
    //at the end:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operator");
}
```

Instead of `Object obj` you should put the class which contains all the fields the 'fieldName' might refer to.

Comment: I guess that will have to do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's the way. Feel free to upvote and mark as a solution. I'll edit your question to add what you've explained in the comments.

Comment: @Kei please have a look at the question edit and tell me if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes! Sums up what my purpose was.

Comment: I believe, my answer is the only applicable solution then. Nevermind, I recommend reading [ask] and [mcve]. These are two tutorials on how to ask a question and not get downvoted. On the other hand this will most often implicate in receiving an answer.

Comment: @Kei I've browsed your questions. You have asked many, but haven't accepted any answer as a solution which is important for the site. In each question, if there is an answer that solved your problem, you should mark it as a solution by clicking on a gray tick below the answer score. This can be changed at any time if a better answer appear. Both of use will be awarded with some reputation then